# Get font color of the current GTK theme

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject

I need to get the font color of the current theme.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806623/how-to-access-the-theming-fonts-and-colors-on-gtk-gnome) that explains it how to do it in C with `gtk_style_lookup_color`, but it seems that the function is deprecated.

Making more researches I found the new function [gtk_style_context_lookup_color](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStyleContext.html#gtk-style-context-lookup-color)

But I have problems understanding the docs. Also, when I try to call it by using `Gtk.style_context_lookup_color( .. )` I get that it doesn't exists!

Is it because I need to call it with something like `GtkStyleContext.style_context_lookup_color(arg1,arg2)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer using [gtk.settings.](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtksettings.html)

```
    settings=Gtk.Settings.get_default()

    colors=settings.get_property("gtk-color-scheme")
    colors=colors.split("\n")

    for color in colors:
        if 'text' in color:
            text_color=color.split(':')[1].strip()
            print text_color
            break
```

It seems that the `"gtk-color-scheme"` property stores all the colors of the theme, so if you are searching for any other color you can find it in the same way!

Comment: Unfortunately, color schemes seem to be deprecated now.

Comment: It seems you're [https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSettings.html](right). What a shame! As of now, it still seems to work.