# Get color scheme from GTK

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, pygtk, gtk3

I am developing a desktop app using Python 3 and GTK3.

I need a button to change its background color when hover, which can be done with this:

```
self.uploadbutton.modify_bg(Gtk.StateType.PRELIGHT, self.color)
```

Until now, I defined a RGB color that matches my own theme, but as I have to release this code, I would like to change that color to one of the established theme colors.

Searching the web, I found [there's a way to do it with GTK2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27962577/get-font-color-of-the-current-gtk-theme/27981847#27981847), but since version 3.8 of GTK, the `gtk-color-scheme` property has been [deprecated](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSettings.html#GtkSettings--gtk-color-scheme).

Is there any other way to respect the user theme colors without using this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now I have found two ways. Both of them are not the answer to your question, because as far as I understand in GTK3 every single element can have it's own styling (including color).

The first one is [official](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/CustomStyle) and says not to mess with themes unless you have tested them and know how exactly your modifications would look. I think it's the best solution since it's not clear at compile-time whether your `self.color` will make it look ok or totally unreadable.

---

The second solution is to obtain full CSS and parse it yourself.

```
    gset = Gtk.Settings.get_default ()
    themename = gset.get_property ("gtk-theme-name")
    prefdark = gset.get_property ("gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme") # it's a boolean
    cprov = Gtk.CssProvider.get_named (themename)
    print (cprov.to_string())
```

Parsing the theme is outside of this question.

Comment: As a month passed and nobody else gave another answer I'll mark yours as accepted, thanks for your time friend :)